# Can't integrate summation with sympy

Tags: python, sympy, algebra

I would like to compute the integral of a summation:

```py
import sympy as sp
t = sp.Symbol("t")
n = sp.Symbol("n", integer=True, positive=True)
sum_term = sp.Sum(sp.exp(-(n*sp.pi)**2 * t), (n, 1, sp.oo))
sp.integrate(sum_term, (t, 0, t)).doit()
```

However, this doesn't calculate the integral:
`Integral(Sum(exp(-pi**2*n**2*t), (n, 1, oo)), (t, 0, t))`

Comment: What do you expect when you use n ∈ [1, ∞]?

Comment: This shouldn't matter since the integral of a summation is the summation of the integrals, right?

Comment: Can you replace `(n, 1, sp.oo)` by `(n, 1, 3)`. Does it what you expect in this case?

Comment: Tried that but it doesn't do as expected either

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this doesn't work but if you interchange the order of the sum and the integral it works:

```
In [5]: import sympy as sym

In [6]: t, n = sym.symbols('t, n')

In [7]: f = sym.exp(-(n*sym.pi)**2 * t)

In [8]: f
Out[8]: exp(-pi**2*n**2*t)

In [11]: e1 = sym.Integral(sym.Sum(f, (n, 1, sym.oo)), (t, 0, sym.oo))

In [12]: e2 = sym.Sum(sym.Integral(f, (t, 0, sym.oo)), (n, 1, sym.oo))

In [13]: e1
Out[13]: Integral(Sum(exp(-pi**2*n**2*t), (n, 1, oo)), (t, 0, oo))

In [14]: e2
Out[14]: Sum(Integral(exp(-pi**2*n**2*t), (t, 0, oo)), (n, 1, oo))

In [15]: e1.doit()
Out[15]: Integral(Sum(exp(-pi**2*n**2*t), (n, 1, oo)), (t, 0, oo))

In [17]: e2.doit()
Out[17]: 1/6
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Exactly I would expect sympy to distribute the integral by default without having to do it manually.